# pandas work on jupyter but not recognized in cmd or anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I want to run a script in .py with `cmd` or anaconda prompt but says pandas can't be recognized.

```
'pandas' in sys.modules
 False
```

the version of python is the correct where these libraries are installed. The correct path is somehow not in connection with the cmd and all the libraries installed with the anaconda are not seen. How to make it work without installing all the modules again?

Comment: u have two python versions ??.
if u run `python --version` in cmd it returns what ??

Comment: 3.6.5. it's the correct

Comment: pip install pandas from command line

Comment: lame question,but,did you import it?

Comment: that is one way but since they are installed i would rather not installing them again because i need to do it for a lot of libraries and I need to connect cmd with the actual installed libraries.

Comment: @user10109563, you did not install it?

Comment: In the script they are imported yes . It is obvious that the issue is steps earlier since they are not recognised in the cmd at all as you can see from the code existing in the question

Comment: The package is installed and works in jupyter but in cmd it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to write the word `python` too.

```
python hx.py
```

now it runs if typed in the anaconda prompt.

All nice.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is fixed with a simple from command line:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

if this doesn't help, I will suggest you to remove all the python packages and do an anaconda reinstall on your system

Comment: i need to find it since it is installed not to installed it again.Am i not saying it right?

Comment: clearly there is an issue with your installation, its not mapped properly or you have a manual path assigned that the os is unable to find. so reinstall or a new install is the best fix

Comment: how to check where pandas is installed?

Comment: it will be something like home/nameofpc/anaconda3/pkgs/pandas-(version)